# Dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7

I am trying to dual boot windows 7 and ubuntu, but I am having issues. First of all, every single tutorial I've read or watched explains how to do this if you have a windows system already setup, and then to install ubuntu alongside it. That is not what I want to do seeing as I already have Ubuntu, but not windows. I downloaded a pre activated win 7 .iso, used unetbootin succesfully to put it on a usb, and rebooted my system. I get the following error:

```
Failed to load COM32 file menu.c32
```

Then it just displays a prompt, and anything I enter in it it returns that it could not load file . PLease help me.

I am using Ubuntu 14.10

Really want to have windows and ubuntu, so that I can play games and stuff. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Back-up every file, remove linux and install Windows and THEN install Ubuntu, otherwise I have no idea how to do it through Linux without getting errors etc.

Comment: ive thought about that, but if there is an easier way id like to try before doing that

Comment: I know how you feel, if I ever stumble accross anything I'll let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to download windows 7 from the net and when booting up the system hit the F number to go to boot system and boot windows 7 then once windows 7 is up and running open Ubuntu.

Comment: didnt understand anything

Comment: try installing windows through command prompt. But like the other person said buck up your files.

Comment: I meant Back-up

Comment: how would i do that? is there a tutorial which explains it?